# how to format bucket name in AWS for saving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hi i have  a lambda function that  is  trying to save to  a bucket:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('starting');
  const { Client } = require('pg');
  const client = new Client();
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  var bucketName =  'arn:aws:s3:us-east-1::my_bucket_name';
  var keyName = 'prova.txt';
  var content = 'This is a sample text file';
  var params = { 'Bucket': bucketName, 'Key': keyName, 'Body': content };
  try {
      console.log('saving...');
      const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
      console.log("Successfully saved object to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log('err');
          console.log(err);

      };
```

But I get the error  below. Know  what i'm doing wrong?

```
  message: "Access point ARN resource should begin with 'accesspoint/'",
  code: 'InvalidAccessPointARN',
  time: 2020-03-21T12:38:33.370Z
}
END RequestId: 31aba537-c25a-45bf-877e-0be8e8f98c95
REPORT RequestId: 31aba537-c25a-45bf-877e-0be8e8f98c95  Duration: 4543.02 ms    Billed Duration: 4600 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 83 MB  Init Duration: 107.67 ms
```

Comment: Do as the error says, add `accesspoint ` to bucket name or maybe key:

`var bucketName =  'arn:aws:s3:us-east-1::accesspoint/my_bucket_name';`

Comment: ` message: 'Access point ARN is not DNS compatible. Got my_bucket',
  code: 'InvalidAccessPointARN',
  time: 2020-03-21T12:47:48.765Z
} `

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket is not accessible at the moment.
Go to your S3 bucket, then navigate to "Access points" tab.

[image: Access points tab]

Create an access point from here.
I believe you need an Internet access point, and to keep things simple, untick the "Block all public access" (not recommended for security).

Once it is created open the access point details and use "Access point ARN" from there.